# What's is the path to Hostinger?

Tags: php, android, hosting

I want to reach my php files that are in Hostinger in my Android studio. Whats is the path for doing that?

```
private static final String URL =    "http://mysql.hostinger.pt/u488015497_park/list.php";
```

Is this path correct?

Comment: Since apparently you refer to the "Hostinger" hosting service (do you?) I suggests you take a look into their documentation or ask their support...

Comment: yes, I am refering to that